# Object doesn't support property or method 'customFromJson' in sharepoint 2013 script

Tags: modal-dialog, sharepoint-2013, clientscript

When iam using
 src="/_layouts/SP.js
src="/_layouts/SP.UI.Dialog.js
 src="/_layouts/SP.Core.js these references iam facing an issue with the error message Object doesn't support property or method 'customFromJson' sp.ribbon.js?rev=mJ6GVWQrgE26i0%2F2QeG%2B%2Bw%3D%3D:2 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my custom master page added Localizable property to false. Working absolutely fine. in office 365 SharePoint 2013 custom master page.

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" language="javascript" LoadAfterUI="True" name="sp.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink2" language="javascript" LoadAfterUI="True" name="sp.ribbon.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink3" language="javascript" LoadAfterUI="True" name="sp.runtime.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink4" language="javascript" LoadAfterUI="True" name="sp.core.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
```